Representing Pi in binary
Say we detect music or video encoded in radio signals from Alpha Centauri. We want to aim a large radio telescope there and blast them with something that's going to get their attention, something simple that shows we're intelligent.
One way would be to transmit a series of prime numbers, repeatedly. But there has been discussion on the philosophy stax about whether that is necessarily an artificial sequence.
If you wanted to transmit the first n digits of pi, You couldn't transmit it as 3, 1, 4, 1... because that's base 10.
So how would you transmit it in binary? How can you indicate where the decimal point goes?
There's a simple n-digit magic number that acts like an ID card for intelligence. All you have to do is transmit it, with no other information.
But is that even possible?
Or does this belong in the Logic Puzzles stax?

You don't need to indicate where the decimal point goes, a reasonably intelligent civilization should just be able to figure it out. I think the primes would also work fine and would arguably be less arbitrary since it's not dependent on a choice of base.

If they're sending music or video, why don't we just send back music or video using the same encoding method they are using?

They might not recognize it as information. If I were making the movie contact, I would have added an easily recognizable header to get their attention. I'd probably even add a recognition layer outside that, consisting of second-long blasts followed by silence.

If you can add a header to get their attention, then there is no reason to send digits/bits of $\pi$. The whole point of sending $\pi$ is the idea it would be recognizable as a signal not resulting from natural process, and thus must be from an intelligent source. Indeed if we could interpret their signals as music/video, then we could use that same format to communicate back to them much more effectively than mucking around with sending numbers.

I would repeatedly send 262 53741 26407 68744 , a large integer close to the Ramanujan's constant $e^{\pi\sqrt{163}}$. The advantage is that is unique and finite.

Here's a method similar to the one most computer use(IEEE-754).
So the first digit in the binary string is the sign of the number(i.e. if it's positive or negative). Now consider if the number was converted to scientific notation(just for simplicity we'll do this in base-10). For example, 3.1 in scientific notation is $3.1*10^0$. Rewrite this so the first part(called the mantissa) is between $0$ and $1$; in this case, it would be $0.31*10^1$. In IEEE-754, if we were doing it in base-10, it would be $0|31|1$; the $0$ is because $3.1$ is positive; the $31$ comes from the part of $0.31$ after the decimal place; the $1$ comes from the $10^1$. This same idea is used in IEEE-754 for binary, once you convert $3$, $3.14$, etc. to a decimal in binary.

Most computers store floating point numbers in binary, with the significand beween $1$ and $2$. Since the most-significant bit is always $1$, that bit is not stored. However, one cannot expect the receiving alien species to be well-versed in IEEE-754 formatting, and thus it would be unsuitable for the purpose.

Frame challenge: is $$\frac{P}{D} = π \approx 3.1415..$$ somehow more logical than
$$\frac{D}{P} = 1/π = 0.3183...$$
?
If not, we could just send the fractional binary number 010100010111110011000000... and avoid the interpretation challenges of the decimal point location.

Don't worry about the decimal point. (Binary point?). $2 \pi$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$ are just as unique as $\pi$. For that matter, if they misinterpret 0 as 1 and vice-versa, they'll get the number $4-\pi$. If the aliens know about $\pi$ and binary then they'll be able to figure it out.
Separately, there's an argument to be made that $2\pi$ might be more obvious than $\pi$ - it's the ratio of a circle's circumference to its radius, it's the period of $\sin$ and $\cos$, etc. It's a historical accident that we use one and not the other. How do we know the aliens don't think of it the other way around?

The tau manifesto

@infinitezero exactly.

An advantage of sending binary digits and not worrying about the decimal place, is that 2π and (π/2) is exactly the same as π.

If we're focusing on sending $\pi$, then there's no real need to worry about the decimal point - the digits themselves should be a sufficiently recognisable sequence (matching A004601 in OEIS), and this also means that if our target aliens subscribe to the $\tau$ manifesto, or use some other base constant that's a power of two multiple of $\pi$ then it doesn't change anything (although if they prefer $\frac{1}{\pi}$ then they'll need to do the conversion, which should still be reasonable).
In terms of the signal itself, we wouldn't necessarily just send it as 1100100100001... with 1 = signal on and 0 = signal off. With current knowledge of signal engineering, we're likely to do things like:

Include a "header" signal at the start, and a "footer" signal at the end.

Use an encoding that includes some redundancy (e.g. sending 1 as 1010 and 0 as 1001).

Use varying signal lengths, e.g. transmit 1 as an on signal for 3 seconds, and 0 as an on signal for 2 seconds.


Beyond that, though, is the question of whether there's something better to send to signal intelligence, but I think that's out of scope here.

I want to recommend two possibilities.
First is sending ten signals separated by a "white space" signal. The ten signals will count up in binary to represent that we are using base-10, and the white space will be an extended 'on' position that we will only use for white space. Following that, we can begin reciting pi, ignoring the decimal.
Second is similar to what we did with the Arecibo message. The length of our message would be a multiple of two primes, so the message can only be laid out in a rectangle in only two ways, one of which does not produce distinct groups of "content". This way our message can be clearly interpreted as a message and deciphered visually.
Simply styling our message like this would probably be a good enough clue that we are here, intelligent, and ready to mingle. But in keeping with the original intent, we would again send 10 characters to establish base-ten, and then use those characters to begin reciting pi.
Hopefully this is what you were looking for!
